# How do I configure dhcpcd to call wpa_supplicant for a specific interface?

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, static-ip

`$ uname -a
Linux pi 4.9.59+ #1047 Sun Oct 29 11:47:10 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux`

System fully updated via `apt`.

I'm aware there are many, many questions and blogs on this topic, but after several days of looking and asking friends I can't find an answer.

My Raspberry Pi Zero W has two wireless interfaces: wlan0 and wlan1.

I want wlan0 to be an AP and wlan1 to connect to an AP.

So I need wlan0 to have a static IP and wlan1 to get one from DHCP over wireless.

If I set a static IP for wlan0 in `dhcpcd.conf`, dhcpcd still calls `wpa_supplicant` and so even with a static IP it joins the AP - which causes conflicts when trying to run `hostapd`.

If I set a static IP for wlan0 via `interfaces`, `dhcpcd` fails because it detected the interface being configured in `interfaces` - *eventhough* I'd added `denyinterface wlan0` to the `dhcpcd.conf`.

I know that `wpa_supplicant` has a command-line parameter for `interface`, but I haven't been able to find a way of limiting which interfaces get passed from the dhcpcd hook.

The question is: what configuration should I use in `dhcpcd.conf` (or elsewhere?) so I can get a static IP address on wlan0 and not have it connect to an AP AND get an IP address via DHCP on wlan1 and have it connect to an AP? *phew*

**UPDATE 1:**

I've tried using `systemctl start dhcpcd@wlan0.service` to have a per-interface config, but there is no `dhcpcd@.service` file, only `dhcpcd.service`.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've added a system unit file (if that's the right word?) for `dhcpcd@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=dhcpcd on %I
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/dhcpcd-%I.pid
ExecStart=/sbin/dhcpcd --config /etc/dhcpcd-%I.conf -A -q -w %I
ExecStop=/sbin/dhcpcd -k %I

[Install]
Alias=multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd@eth0.service
```

(Modified from: https://github.com/devkral/systemd-arch-units/blob/master/service/dhcpcd@.service)

This means I can successfully apply an interface-specific config into which I put a static IP address configuration and `nohook wpa_supplicant`.

This correctly doesn't call `wpa_supplicant`, but doesn't seem to set the IP address either. No errors on run and I can see it's loading the correct conf file, but `ip addr` shows no IP address on the interface.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by using the interface-specific unit (`/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service`), with an interface-specific `dhcpcd.conf`.

For `wlan0`, static IP address and no `wpa_supplicant`:

`/etc/dhcpcd-wlan0.conf`

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address==192.168.100.1/24

denyinterfaces wlan0    # don't send DHCP requests
nohook wpa_supplicant   # don't call the wpa_supplicant hook
```

For `wlan1`, no changes to the default `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, but had to create an interface-specific version:

```
cp /etc/dhcpcd.conf /etc/dhcpcd-wlan1.conf
```

Then, start `dhcpcd` for each interface:

```
systemctl start dhcpcd@wlan0
systemctl start dhcpcd@wlan1
```

**UPDATE**

Although this is *an* answer, @Nasha above was correct: you can specify a different `wpa_supplicant.conf` file per interface. Leaving this (wrong) answer here as it may prove useful.

Comment: I think this is a better way to do it for the host AP / client AP case, as for this case we want to disable wpa_supplicant completely for the host AP. Thanks for leaving the answer up! :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a unit for that. Use `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. From the man pages:

> **denyinterfaces pattern**
>
> When discovering interfaces, the interface name must not match pattern which is a space or comma separated list of patterns passed to fnmatch(3).

So just add `denyinterfaces wlan1` to `dhcpcd.conf` and dhcpcd will ignore that interface when sending DHCP requests.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In this case, can I still configure the static IP address in `dhcpcd.conf` or would I need to do it somewhere else, like `interfaces`?

Comment: Although this prevents DHCP requests being sent for the denied interface, it is still included in the interfaces when hooks are executed. Therefore, `wpa_supplicant` is still called for the denied interface. I'm trying to avoid `wpa_supplicant` being called for the denied interface.

Comment: You don't have to prevent `wpa_supplicant` from being called for the denied interface as the former is also responsible for putting the wireless adapter in access point mode instead of just client mode. Just find a way to provide it with 2 different configs... although I'm almost certain it's possible to configure multiple adapters in different modes from the same one and only `wpa_supplicant.conf`. Someone can confirm?

Comment: you're right about the `wpa_supplicant.conf` per interface! `10-wpa_supplicant` hook shows the list of files, in order, that are checked. `wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf` is at the top of the list. If you update the answer I can mark it as the correct one?

Comment: @Bridgey I don't have my Pi accessible for the moment (all my available machines are Gentoo), I'll check that as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1  - Using nohook wpa_supplicant**

The /etc/dhcpcd.conf configuration file of *dhcpcd* can be edited to define which wireless interfaces need *wpa_supplicant*.

For each identified interface, *dhcpcd* executes all scripts (hooks) found in */lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks* in lexical order. One of the scripts is *10-wpa_supplicant*, which starts *wpa_supplicant*. It can be edited, e.g., to customize *wpa_supplicant* command-line parameters.

In order to disable the *wpa_supplicant* hook for an interface, use `nohook wpa_supplicant` for that interface.

Example:

```
interface wlan1 # these two lines are not strictly needed, as wlan0 uses the default configuration
    dhcp

interface wlan0 # this defines static addressing and netmask to wlan0, uses only IP V4 addressing and disables wpa_supplicant for this interface
    static ip_address=192.168.50.1/24
    ipv4only
    nohook wpa_supplicant
```

In the above example, the *wlan1* interface will start by default all its hooks, including the *wpa_supplicant* hook, which runs *wpa_supplicant* with the following command-line arguments:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan1 -Dnl80211,wext
```

Also, a DHCP client is configured for this interface (that is the default configuration; in other terms, the *wlan1* entry is redundant).

In the same example, the *wlan0* interface (e.g, the one to be used as AP), defines a static IP address and network mask: Also, it disables the *wpa_supplicant* hook, so that *wpa_supplicant* is not activated for this interface.

**Option 2 - Using denyinterfaces**

The *denyinterfaces* directive of */etc/dhcpcd.conf* disables processing specific interfaces. In this case, specific configurations, like setting a static IP address of an interface, should be done by different services (like *systemd-networkd* via configuration files in */etc/systemd/network/* directory).

Example:

```
denyinterfaces wlan0 # wlan0 will not be managed with default settings (e.g., running wpa_supplicant hook). Besides, all subsequent configurations related to wlan0 will be ignored.
```

**Option 3 - Disabling or uninstalling dhcpcd5**

*dhcpcd* can be disabled using the following command:

```
systemctl disable dhcpcd
```

Or it can also be uninstalled:

```
sudo apt-get --autoremove purge dhcpcd5
```

After disabling or uninstalling the *dhcpcd* service, *wpa_supplicant* can be either activated by configuring the old [/etc/network/interfaces](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html), or via specific service.

Example with */etc/network/interfaces*:

```
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Example to run *wpa_supplicant* with a specific service on a specific interface (*wlan1* in this case):

```
SYSTEMD_EDITOR=tee systemctl edit --force --full wpa_supplicant@.service <<\EOF
[Unit]
Description= WPA supplicant on wlan%i interface
Before=network.target
After=dbus.service
Wants=network.target

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -iwlan%i -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/ /wpa_supplicant_wlan%i.conf -Dnl80211,wext

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=dbus-fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service
EOF

systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@1.service
systemctl start wpa_supplicant@1.service
rfkill unblock wlan
```

The following command will be launched:

```
/sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -iwlan1 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_wlan1.conf -Dnl80211,wext
```